# I can't change the default apps in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

Since a few days ago I can't change the default applications on Windows 10, and that applies to file extensions as well.

This is a gif showing what happens when I try to change the default internet browser

[image]

I have Windows 10 Home Edition, Version 1511 (OS Build 10586.164).

I've looked around and I haven't found anyone with this problem, I don't know what to do and It's really annoying.

If someone could help me with this I would really appreciate it.

Comment: One of the solutions / or workarounds here should help: http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/default-apps-not-working-windows-10/

Comment: Thanks. Apparently the problem was that I recently connected an app to onedrive but I couldn't remove the app as the page says. In the end the "Set defaults by app" worked fine.

Comment: voting up for the gif, wish we could all do that :) what tool did you use to create the gift

Comment: I used ScreenToGif (https://screentogif.codeplex.com/) it comes really handy for gamedev.

Comment: Also voted up because of the cool gif which explains the problem and the frustration entailed perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this too, because using Settings > System > Default apps has no effect for me, and using Explorer > Right Click > Open With > Choose Default Program *also has no effect*. For me, the venerable Control Panel did the job.

Control Panel > Default Programs > Set Your Default Programs

Not only is the Control Panel interface more powerful, but its settings actually have an effect.

Comment: Also does absolutely nothing on my Windows 10 Enterprise (1803). I just can't set an app as a default for file types. Ridiculous!

Comment: @mrt I'm in the same possition as you, so there are two options AFAIK uninstall update [KB4458469](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4458469/windows-10-update-kb4458469#section-3) or wait it out apparently they intend to fix it by the end of november. If you read on that page it mentions it.

Comment: I did "Control Panel > Default Programs > Set Your Default Programs" and landed at the same place as with "Settings > System > Default apps" - no effect.

Answer (score -1):

I managed to get the app to save booting in safe mode then setting app under properties